# How to store sqlalchemy record object into memcache

Tags: python, serialization, sqlalchemy, memcached

code :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
DBSession = sessionmaker()
DBSession.bind = engine
session = DBSession()
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:password@localhost/db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class Accounts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
```

I am trying to store sqlalchemy record object into memcache

```
from pymemcache.client.base import Client
client = Client(('localhost', 11211))
client.set('testkey', session.query(Users).get(1))
```

It is storing string object instead of User object
output : `'<__main__.Users object at 0x105b69b10>'`

Any help ?

Thanks advance

Comment: Can you post more code, specifically the part where you retrieve and print the User object from memcache?

Comment: Can u check now

Comment: Still not seeing where you print the User object.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't so much about how to store a `SQLAlchemy` object but rather how to store any Object instance.

This is from [docstring](https://pymemcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc/pymemcache.client.base.html#pymemcache.client.base.Client) of the pymemcache `Client` class that you've imported:

> Values must have a **str**() method to convert themselves to a byte
>   string.

You haven't included a definition of the `Users` class that you are querying your database with so I can only assume you haven't overridden `__str__`. Therefore, when `pymemcache` tries to convert your object into a byte string, it is calling python's default `__str__` implementation and storing that.

Answer (score 0):

As @SuperShoot mentions in their answer, `pymemcache` expects to store a `str` representation. Since your SQLAlchemy model instance (record) is not natively a `str` representation, `pymemcache` tries to call its default `__str__()` method, which produces an undesired result.

What you need is an interim step that will serialize your SQLAlchemy model instance to a `str` of one structure or another. This makes your logical round-trippable flow:

1. Serialize your model instance to a `str` of one structure or another.
2. Store the serialized `str` using `pymemcache`.
3. When retrieving the `str` from `pymemcache`, de-serialize it into a SQLAlchemy model instance to continue working easily with it in your Python code.

This can be a bit complicated with SQLAlchemy models, which is why I recommend using the [SQLAthanor](https://github.com/insightindustry/sqlathanor) library (full disclosure: I'm the author). It lets you serialize your SQLAlchemy model to CSV, JSON, or YAML - which you can then persist to memcache. And it also lets you easily de-serialize a CSV, JSON, or YAML string into a SQLAlchemy model instance as well, letting you easily maintain the whole flow described above.

There's a lot more functionality to the library which you can read about on the docs page: https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The important bit to remember is that when using SQLAthanor, you'll need to decide what format you want to store your data in (I recommend JSON or YAML), and then explicitly configure the columns/attributes you want to have serialized to that format (this is a security feature in the library). Because your code snippet shows that you're using Declarative Reflection, you'll probably want to look at the following sections of the documentation for how to configure SQLAthanor:

- https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#using-declarative-reflection-with-sqlathanor
- https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-sqlathanor-with-sqlalchemy-reflection

Hope this helps!